# How to make a recursive function to get a max money earned in a family?

Tags: python, recursion

So we have a dict of the family and who is who's kid. (it's a global variable)

```
kids= {
"Adam": ["Matjaž", "Cilka", "Daniel"],
"Aleksander": [],
"Alenka": [],
"Barbara": [],
"Cilka": [],
"Daniel": ["Elizabeta", "Hans"],
"Erik": [],
"Elizabeta": ["Ludvik", "Jurij", "Barbara"],
"Franc": [],
"Herman": ["Margareta"],
"Hans": ["Herman", "Erik"],
"Jožef": ["Alenka", "Aleksander", "Petra"],
"Jurij": ["Franc", "Jožef"],
"Ludvik": [],
"Margareta": [],
"Matjaž": ["Viljem"],
"Petra": [],
"Tadeja": [],
"Viljem": ["Tadeja"],
}
```

Now we have a recursive function:

```
def richest(person, money):
```

Money is a local variable, that has the amount of money of each person.

```
money = {
        "Adam": 42,
        "Aleksander": 3,
        "Alenka": 3,
        "Barbara": 37,
        "Cilka": 242,
        "Daniel": 4,
        "Erik": 32,
        "Elizabeta": 8,
        "Franc": 16,
        "Herman": 12,
        "Hans": 55,
        "Jožef": 7,
        "Jurij": 5,
        "Ludvik": 37,
        "Margareta": 20,
        "Matjaž": 142,
        "Petra": 3,
        "Tadeja": 45,
        "Viljem": 55
    }
```

When I call the function `richest("Elizabeta", money)` it should return the person/s with the max money and the amount of money. 
In this case that would return: `[("Ludvik", 37), ("Barbara", 37)]`

I've tried to make a recursive function but it doesn't work properly.

```
def richest(person, money):
      people=[]
      for kid in kids[person]:
         #goes for each kid of that person and their kids.
      return #somehow append it into the people array
```

What am I doing wrong could someone help me? I've also tried something with the the generator but it appended [None] into each kid so it didn't work too..

Comment: How are you achieving the total amount of money for each person? Are you summing the amounts for each child the person has?

Comment: The variable money is the amount of each persons money earned. I need to make a recursive function that checks. Oh "Elizabeta": ["Ludvik", "Jurij", "Barbara"]. So there are 3 people and for these 3 people check their kids and so on... Once you have gone through all of their descendants  return the name and amount of money for the person/s (can be more than 1) witch have the most amount of money.

Comment: I don't have time but here is the step:
1- You have to write a function to get all child with the maximum value as dictionnary because the built-in max function returns just one
2- In the richest function, you call the the first function on every child, and loop over the list you get. On each items, you will call richest function and append all result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def richest(person, money):
  for kid in kids[person]:
     money = richest(kid, money) + money
  return money[person]

people=[]
for person in kid:
    people.append(person, richest(person, money[person]))
```

You have to have the people list outside the recursive, otherwise makes no sense to append the person to a list whose scope is of a function whose parameter is a person, if you want, than it must have the **person list** as a parameter as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that solves your problem recursively:

```
def richest(person, money):
    people = [(person, money[person])]
    for child in kids[person]:
        # Recursively find the richest descendants of this child (including this child)
        descendants = richest(child, money)
        # Merge with currently found richest people in the branch
        if descendants:
            if descendants[0][1] > people[0][1]:
                # Descendants are the new richest people
                people = descendants
            elif descendants[0][1] == people[0][1]:
                # Descendants are as rich as previosly found richest people
                people += descendants
    return people
```

(We compare only money of the first person in lists `descendants` and `people` because all of the people in both lists are equally wealthy.)